# Как менять true false по клику на блок?

Tags: javascript, jquery, swiper

Подскажите , как в javascript файле менять значение с true на false и обратно при клике?
Вот образец:
ucheba486.site

Как при клике на красный блок (.box) поменять значение у Слайдера опции dynamicBullets: true на false (и обратно) ?

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
 pagination: {
  el: '.swiper-pagination',
  dynamicBullets: true,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Вашему красному блоку, добавьте **ID**, 
вот так это может выглядеть  ---
`<div class="box" id="box"></div>`

---

```
 let dynamicBulletsState = true


 var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
 pagination: {
  el: '.swiper-pagination',
  dynamicBullets: dynamicBulletsState,
  },
});
```

---

```
document.getElementById("box").addEventListener("click", () => {
  dynamicBulletsState ? false : true
})
```